# Can Run react-native directly to iOS device?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

in android we can run directly to android device with adb and sdk installed. so can i run react-native app to iOS device directly without installing iOS emulator or xcode?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You can run your React-Native app directly in connected device, Using the following command without open xcode.

> react-native run-ios --device="device_name"

But xcode must be install in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, you need xcode

Answer (score -1):

Enter this in terminal

```
react-native run-ios --simulator=”iPhone 11 Pro Max”
```

Comment: Question is about, How to run on device (real iPhone) not on Simulator.